# Removing a portion of the URL in Yii 2.0

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

If I enter the URL:

```
http://localhost/third/web/calculator
```

it just works fine. I now want to remove the `web` portion from the URL. I currently do not have .htaccess. And if I enter `http://localhost/third/calculator` it shows object not found.

I added this .htaccess in the root folder of the project:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/third/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/third/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
```

Now if I enter `http://localhost/third/calculator` it shows the congratulations page of yii2, instead of the calculator page. If  click in any other tabs like login with link `<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>` the url shows the web still.

Comment: hello.I used this tutorial for removing web from url   http://tutsnare.com/remove-web-from-url-in-yii2/

Answer (score 1):

First you change **config->web.php**

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
]
```

Add **.htaccess** file in your project root directory

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/.+)?$ web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1
```

Also you have to add `.htaccess` file in **your_project->web** directory

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: tried exactly this. but still if i enter http://localhost/third/calculator it shows the congratulations page of yii2.And if i click in any other tabs the url shows the web.