# Routing url in Yii2 with xampp

Tags: php, apache, routes, yii2

My basic project is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\site.local\www`
I can run my app whith `http://site.local/basic/web/index.php`
But I want run it as `http://site.local/index.php`
How can I solve this problem?
I changes my `httpd.conf`  :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site.local/www/basic/web"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/site.local/www/basic/web">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: www folder isn't required in xampp.see this link  for remove web http://blog.neattutorials.com/seo-friendly-urls-in-yii2/

Comment: Try this settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584390/removing-web-from-url-yii2/38645479#38645479

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simply named Virtual Host. In `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` add the following:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.10.80:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site.local/www/basic/web"               
    ServerName site.local
    ErrorLog "logs/site.local.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, run the notepad **as administrator** and from it open the **hosts** file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the following line to its end:

```
127.0.10.80 site.local
```

Save the both files and restart the Apache Server and restore the default `.httaccess`.

**Notice**: the IP 127.0.10.80 is called internal loop IP and it is dedicated for local hosting. It may be any other value starts with 127, such as 127.0.0.1 (the default one)